# Animate change of view background not happening smoothly

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I am trying to animate the back ground of my activity 
What i have done is

```
 ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.toggle_image);
    final TransitionDrawable td = new TransitionDrawable( new Drawable[] {
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.welcomeimagetoggle1),
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.welcomeimagetoggle2)
    });

    image .setImageDrawable(td);
    td.startTransition(3000);
    td.reverseTransition(3000);

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Do something after 100ms
            td.startTransition(3000);
            td.reverseTransition(3000);
            handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);
        }
    }, 3000);
```

It's working properly but the problem is while the timer ends the change happening is to smooth , there is a sudden movement. How can i avoid that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use [this library (DexMovingImageView)](https://github.com/dexlex/DexMovingImageView) instead. 
It offers some cool transitions (check their demo). In your case, use the DexCrossFadeImageView with multiple images.
Don't forget to make the window background of your activity transparent to [avoid overdraw](http://www.curious-creature.com/docs/android-performance-case-study-1.html).

**UPDATE :** About the padding, check the scaletype. 
As for animation, here's [KenBurnsView](https://github.com/flavioarfaria/KenBurnsView) (ImageView animated by Ken Burns effect), [Motion](https://github.com/nvanbenschoten/motion) (ImageView with a parallax effect that reacts to the device's tilt) and finally [LoyalNativeSlider](https://github.com/jjhesk/LoyalNativeSlider) (An image slider with many cool animations).
 Hope this helps!

Comment: it's a good library, Do you know any library that help in movement and bouncing animation ?

Comment: i am getting a padding on both left and right side , do you know why this is chapping?